# Will adding new devices make old provisioning profiles invalid?

Tags: ios, ios-provisioning

I'm looking to add a new device to a provisioning profile for an app I'm developing. My concern is that there are already a few devices outside our office running a test build that was installed using an existing version of the provisioning profile.

If I update the the provisioning profile to include the new devices, will the provisioning profile on the existing devices become invalid and stop that existing version of the app from running properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the old provisioning profile(s) will remain valid. The only way for an app to expire is if the development certificate used to sign the code/profile is revoked or expires.

Comment: As Mike stated, the old profile will work if you update the profile by ADDING a device.  However, if you remove one, all the profiles associated to that device will be deactivated.